# Functional $Gram : S^m(S^2 V)^* \otimes S^2(\bigwedge^m V) \to \mathbb R$ and Gram determinant in invariant terms

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

Let $V$ be an vector space over $\mathbb R$. Let $B \otimes ... \otimes B \in S^m(S^2 V)^* = ((S^2 V^*)^{\otimes m})^{S_m} \subset  (S^2 V^*)^{\otimes m}$ where $B \in (S^2 V)^*$ any symmetric bilinear form (not necessarily non-degenerate, not necessarily non-negative definite), and
$v_1\wedge...\wedge v_m \odot w_1\wedge...\wedge w_m \in S^2(\bigwedge^m V)$. Then we can define $$Gram(B \otimes ... \otimes B ,v_1\wedge...\wedge v_m \odot w_1\wedge...\wedge w_m) = \det (B(v_i,w_j))_{i,j=1..m}.$$ It is easy to check (I hope I'm not mistaken) that this construction gives us a linear functional
$$Gram : S^m(S^2 V)^* \otimes S^2(\wedge^m V) \to \mathbb R.$$ Is there some kind of "hidden algebra" around this functional (maybe $GL_n$ representations and so on) or more global picture? Can we describe it using symbols $\alpha \odot \beta$ instead $v_1\wedge...\wedge v_m \odot w_1\wedge...\wedge w_m$? Maybe some consequences for differential geometry (this gives us a section of the corresponding vector bundle)? It is strange for me that such functional even exist I got used to the fact that the naturally defined functionals appear as traces $W \otimes W^* \to \mathbb R$. Of course if $B$ is standart scalar product on $V=\mathbb R^n$ and $v_i=w_i$ we will obtain usual Gram determinant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, if $B : V \otimes W \to k$ is bilinear (note the appearance of two vector spaces!), $k$ any field, then it induces a bilinear map on exterior powers

$$\wedge^n(B) : \wedge^n(V) \otimes \wedge^n(W) \to k$$

given by the determinant of the Gram matrix, which will be symmetric if $W = V$ and $B$ is symmetric. Note that we do not need to assume that either $V$ or $W$ is finite-dimensional here.

If $W$ is finite-dimensional $B$ corresponds to a map $B' : V \to W^{\ast}$ which has an exterior power in the usual sense $\Lambda^n(B') : \wedge^n(V) \to \wedge^n(W^{\ast})$, and then it should be true (but I haven't checked) that $\wedge^n(B)$ is the bilinear form corresponding to this map under a suitable natural identification

$$\wedge^n(W^{\ast}) \cong \wedge^n(W)^{\ast}.$$

In other words, in the finite-dimensional case the question should reduce by functoriality from an arbitrary bilinear form $B$ to the case of the dual pairing $\text{eval} : V^{\ast} \otimes V \to k$. So the question is to understand why there is a natural dual pairing

$$\wedge^n(V^{\ast}) \otimes \wedge^n(V) \to k.$$

Hopefully in this form things look a bit more intuitive, although personally I also find something confusing about this map; you can see me be confused about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44179/signs-in-the-natural-map-lambdak-v-otimes-lambdak-v-to-bbbk/44183#44183) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1529404/induced-bilinear-form-on-exterior-powers-towards-a-global-hodge-star-operator/1529437#1529437).

**Edit:** Okay, I'm happier now. In the second answer I linked to above I suggest the following strategy, which works: you can naturally and freely extend every linear functional $f \in V^{\ast}$ to a [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra)) of degree $-1$ on $\wedge^{\bullet}(V)$ by extending via the Leibniz rule. By the universal property of the exterior algebra this extends to an action of $\wedge^{\bullet}(V^{\ast})$ on $\wedge^{\bullet}(V)$ by "differential operators" and the pairing $\wedge^n(V^{\ast}) \otimes \wedge^n(V) \to k$ is a restriction of this map. The more general map is

$$\wedge^m(V^{\ast}) \otimes \wedge^n(V) \to \wedge^{n-m}(V)$$

for $m \le n$. For example when $m = 1$ it's given by

$$f(v_1 \wedge \dots \wedge v_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1} f(v_i) \left( v_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \hat{v_i} \dots \wedge v_n \right)$$

where the hat means that $v_i$ is omitted. To get $m = 2$ we apply a second derivation to the above expression and we get a sum of $n(n-1)$ terms, etc. When $m = n$ we get

$$(f_1 \wedge \dots \wedge f_n)(v_1 \wedge \dots \wedge v_n) = (-1)^{ {n \choose 2} } \sum_{\pi \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\pi) f_i(v_{\sigma(i)})$$

which is, up to that pesky global sign, the full Leibniz formula for the Gram determinant, as desired. I am still a little unhappy that this description isn't obviously symmetric in $V$ and $V^{\ast}$: somehow we should be talking about a mutual action of each of $\wedge^{\bullet}(V)$ and $\wedge^{\bullet}(V^{\ast})$ on the other, or some kind of biderivation, or something...

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you!

Comment: @kp9r4d: well, I'm actually still pretty unsatisfied (see also my edit at the end, I was being too cavalier). Among other things we have not really explained the presence of the determinant. I think there's more to say here and I haven't quite said it.

Comment: Okay, after reading a bit more I'm now worried I may have said something actually *false*. Hmm.

Comment: I also, after thinking a little, realized that I did not fully understand everything. I'll take the accepted answer for now (I'm sorry) so as not to scare people who might have something to write. If no one answers, I will definitely return :)

Comment: No, you're right, this isn't an answer yet. Here's something very canonical I definitely believe in: exterior product defines a natural nondegenerate pairing $\wedge^n(V) \otimes \wedge^{d-n}(V) \to \wedge^d(V)$ (where $d = \dim V$), and this produces an identification $\wedge^n(V)^{\ast} \cong \wedge^{d-n}(V) \otimes \wedge^d(V)^{\ast}$. This seems more like it's on the right track because the top exterior power actually appears but we still have to say something about $V^{\ast}$.

Comment: I believe that I have no problem with identification $\wedge(V^*) \cong \wedge(V)^*$ but I still interested about the whole morphism $Gram$ and not just the case when one parameter is fixed $\Lambda(B)$ (although, perhaps, there is nothing smart about it)

Comment: @kp9r4d: if you have any natural procedure for taking a tensor of some type and getting a tensor of another type, you've written down a single large invariant tensor. This is a general phenomenon not specific to this case. For example, dualization takes a map $f : V \to W$ and produces a map $W^{\ast} \to V^{\ast}$, and so it can be understood as a distinguished (in particular, $GL(V) \times GL(W)$-invariant) element of $\text{Hom}(V, W)^{\ast} \otimes \text{Hom}(W^{\ast}, V^{\ast})$ (suitably unwound it's the distinguished element corresponding to a tensor product of coevaluation maps).

Comment: Hm, you are right, I see now that this is actually a function of type $S^2(\wedge^m V)^* \otimes S^2(\wedge^m V) \to \mathbb R$, and now it looks like a trace and I am completely satisfied.  I understand why the map $\Lambda^k(V^*) \to \Lambda^k(V)^*$ looks not canonical to you, but I learned to live with it :)

Comment: Okay, I double-checked that the derivation argument I suggested in an old post actually works. I think what is going on abstractly is we are taking some kind of Weyl-Clifford algebra of $V \oplus V^{\ast}$ equipped with the dual pairing regarded as a quadratic form. That produces all of the maps I know how to write down using the derivation argument all at once and is manifestly symmetric in $V$ and $V^{\ast}$, I think...